# By using JasperPHP library not able to generate Chinese language PDF in laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, pdf, jasper-reports, laravel-5.7

I am using `Laravel 5.7` include `JasperPHP` library, while generating `.rtf` file, it is download properly. But while generating PDF file. It shown

> "Exception in thread "main"
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Could not load the
>   following font:".

Kindly suggest what are steps to follows & fix this issue. Whether we using `JasperPHP` Library is right or not to generating Chinese Language.

**Laravel Code:**

```
$outputfile = time().'_Checklist'; $extension = "pdf"; $jasperphp = new JasperPHP; $jasperphp->process('test.jrxml', $outputfile, array($extension), array(), array())->execute();
```

**.jrxmlCode:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><jasperReport xmlns="jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report name" > <staticText><reportElement x="141" y="33" width="192" height="22" />    <textElement>   <font fontName="SimSun" isBold="false" pdfFontName="SimSun" pdfEncoding="UniGB-UCS2-H" isPdfEmbedded="false"/></textElement><text><![CDATA[Chinese Characters]]></text></staticText>
```

I am using Laravel 5.7 include JasperPHP library, in .jrxml file contains Chinese Language. I generate .jrxml file in Jaspersoft iReport Designer 5.6.0, install font "Arial Unicode MS" and "SimSun" font in **"Options->Font->"Install Font"** and "Export as Extensions" include .jar & .xml file in sources folder.

But it won't work.

Kindly need suggestion..

Comment: make sure to include the piece of code during posting your question.

Comment: Laravel Code: $outputfile =  time().'_Checklist';        $extension = "pdf";          $jasperphp = new JasperPHP;  $jasperphp->process('test.jrxml',  $outputfile, array($extension), array(), array())->execute();

Comment: .jrxmlCode:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report name" >           <staticText><reportElement x="141" y="33" width="192" height="22" /> <textElement> <font fontName="SimSun" isBold="false" pdfFontName="SimSun" pdfEncoding="UniGB-UCS2-H" isPdfEmbedded="false"/></textElement><text><![CDATA[Chinese Characters]]></text></staticText>

Comment: Above two are Piece of code which are used by me..

Comment: @VikashPathak added my code